# Sanity: Validate Array items using native Sanity URL validations

Tags: sanity

I'm creating a Sanity schema for a list of organisations which we will be importing over. I have a field called domains which is an array of domains linked to an organisation. None of these domains have been saved with a domain scheme. I.e. Not https://www.org.com, they are all saved as [www.org.com](http://www.org.com). So I want to set the validation on this field to allowRelative: true. However, I cannot get the validation on the array to validate the items themselves. It appears to only validate the whole array. How do I set it up that it is performing validation on the URL items within the array using the Sanity built in validations for URL?

```
export const organisation = defineType({
  name: 'organisation',
  title: 'Organisation',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    // ....
    defineField({
      name: 'domains',
      title: 'Domains',
      description: 'Domains of the organisation',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'url' }],
      options: {
        sortable: true,
      },
      validation: (Rule: ArrayRule<UrlRule[]>) => Rule.uri({ allowRelative: true }),
    }),
    // ....
  ],
});
```

This is what I have been trying. The error I get is this:

> Error: Validator for flag "uri" not found for type "Array"

I've also tried implementing something similar to the docs here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/validation#9e69d5db6f72

But this is using a custom rule for each of the items within the array. I want to use the native Sanity validation rules on each item.